# Pandas read_sql doesn't use unpersisted objects sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, orm, sqlalchemy

Seems like the convenience function of reading a query into a pandas data frame doesn't read in anything that hasn't been commited (i.e. objects that are still in the session but have not been persisted yet).

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug?

```
>> s = Session()

>> s.add(Foo(id=1, data='A'))

>> query = s.query(Foo).filter(id==1)

>> print 1, query.all()
[<Foo('A')>]

>> print 2, len(pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind))
0

>> s.commit()

>> print pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind)
  data  id
0    A   1
```

Comment: Well, unpersisted objects don't exist in the database and therefore cannot be queried. I don't know what you expected. If all you want is to be able to roll back later, use `s.flush()`, which persists the objects into the database but does not commit the transaction.

Comment: @univerio well I expected the same behavior as in sqlalchemy. When I call session.query natively using sqlalchemy the object is returned. Also, s.flush() doesn't work either. Needs a full commit :/  That's actually the main reason I figured this may be a bug...

Comment: That's because you have `autoflush` turned on. It basically calls `.flush()` for you before you try to query anything.

Comment: `.flush()` doesn't work because you've given `read_sql` the engine, not the connection associated with the current session. Try `.read_sql(..., s.connection())`.

Comment: Nope @univerio I have autflush off. And anyway, if I did, wouldn't you expect it to be returned in the "print 2" line?

Comment: @univerio ok will give the s.connection() a try!

Comment: If `autoflush` is on, any queries made with the session will automatically flush the session, but because you're making a query outside of the session (i.e. using the engine directly), it won't autoflush.

Comment: OK awesome! using the s.connection() works!

Comment: @univerio You should add the `s.connection()` solution down below. It solved my problem, and I'd be happy to give you an upvote for the solution. Was having problems connecting to the correct database, and doing `query.session.bind` seemed to reset whatever statements had been executed before calling `read_sql`.